# UITableView scrolls slow after downloading cell images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I am trying to download some thumbnail from server and then display them in each cell :

```
// displaying image...
dictionary = [newsFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"image"]]]];
cell.imageView.image = [image imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(55, 55)];
```

but after downloading and displaying images, the table view scrolls slowly!

Comment: You should be using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Comment: I did , but I did not write it to above code , by the way I edited my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` method is a **synchronous** request. It blocks the thread where is running until the request is done.

You should avoid this type of interaction if you run this on the main thread. This thread will be frozen and the user will be disappointed ;)

You have many solutions for this. A simple one is to use third library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Both have categories around `UIImageView` class that allows to use them in a simple manner. For example, using `UIImageView+AFNetworking` you should do like the following:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:yourURL placeholderImage:yourPlaceholderImage];
```

Comment: Thanks that was great , but pictures won't be appear until I scroll the thable , how can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I think You are trying to say this.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.YourImageUrl.com"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
            NSData * data,
            NSError * error) {
    if (!error){
            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        // Now workout with the image
    }

}];
```

This will make the asynchronous call, and load the images after tableview loaded i.e when the image load complete the image will show but the table will be loaded when the table view  is needed to load.

Answer (score 1):

Directly use like this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"image"]]]];
```

It takes the main thread, so you can't scroll befor download your Image.So You add NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate add this protocol and download image by

Insert these lines of coding where you want to download Your Image

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request   delegate:self];
    received_data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [connection start];
```

These lines triggers these delegates to download data.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [received_data setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [received_data appendData:data];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //Use your download image
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:received_data];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AFNetworking will get you a better feel. There is a `UIImageView` category as part of the project that will insert a temporary image, while switching to a background thread to download the real image.

That will keep the image download from locking the main thread. Once the image is downloaded the temporary image will be swapped out for you.

Here's a nice tutorial that includes some pointers on using the `UIImageView` category [AFNetworking crash course](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course).

Answer (score 0):

I have written an answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624875/1375695

which explains how to use Grand Central Despatch to keep your table scrolling smoothly while your images are downloading in the background. That answer doesn't mandate the use of a 3rd party library.  Although - as Andrew and Flexaddicted have mentioned - there are libraries which will provide a solution for you - it might be worth reading so that you can understand what needs to happen under the hood.

Note that in my proposed solution, you could still use your synchronous method to actually get the data from the network:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:
                      [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                       [NSURL URLWithString:
                        [dictionary objectForKey:@"image"]]]];
```

as it would be called on an asynchronous background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the AFNetworking framework as @flexaddicted has recommended (`UIImageView+AFNetworking`). Also, check out the Sensible TableView framework. It should be able to automatically fetch all data from the web service and display them in the table view, and will also automatically handle all asynch image downloading. Should save you a bunch of work.

Answer (score 0):

For More convenience to download image use EGOImageLoader/EGOImageView
Download this class by this link

https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading