# Loading images asynchronously, wrong image in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in which I am loading multiple images into. From what Ive been reading, in order to match the correct image to each cell I need to subclass `UIImageView` and get the image there. Because every time I `collectionView reloadData`, some images duplicate and they are all out of order. But I am unsure how to do this and haven't found any tutorials. I am using Parse for a database.

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
albumImageCell *cell = (albumImageCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[albumImageCell alloc]init];
     }

     PFObject *temp = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     PFFile *file = [temp objectForKey:@"imageThumbnail"];

     if (![cell.hasImage isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
         dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{
             NSData *data = [file getData];
                 if (data) {
                     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                         cell.imageView.image = image;
                         cell.hasImage = @"YES";
                     });

                 }
         });
     }

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: By the time the `dispatch_async` returns, the very `UICollectionViewCell` you are assigning the data to may have already been reassigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was subclassing `UIImaveView` and then passing the image file in `cellForRow`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
albumImageCell *cell = (albumImageCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[albumImageCell alloc]init];
    }

    PFObject *temp = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFFile *file = [temp objectForKey:@"imageThumbnail"];

    [cell.imageView setFile:file];

    return cell;
}
```

---

And then in the `customImageView` -

```
- (void) setFile:(PFFile *)file {

    NSString *requestURL = file.url; // Save copy of url locally (will not change in block)
    [self setUrl:file.url]; // Save copy of url on the instance
    self.image = nil;
    [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            if ([requestURL isEqualToString:self.url]) {
                [self setImage:image];
                [self setNeedsDisplay];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error on fetching file");
        }
    }];
}
```

But this gets Data every time the user scrolls to a new cell. So Im still trying to figure out how to match a particular image to a cell, without getting data every time.

Answer (score 7):

One way to solve this is to re-query the collection view for the cell again once you're back on the main queue. This code should work:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
albumImageCell *cell = (albumImageCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[albumImageCell alloc]init];
     }

     PFObject *temp = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     PFFile *file = [temp objectForKey:@"imageThumbnail"];

     if (![cell.hasImage isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
         dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{
             NSData *data = [file getData];
                 if (data) {
                     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                         // cellAgain will be the actual cell at that index path, if it is visible. 
                         // If it is not visible, cellAgain will be nil.
                         albumImageCell *cellAgain = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                         cellAgain.imageView.image = image;
                         cellAgain.hasImage = @"YES";
                     });

                 }
         });
     }

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Not only do you need to requery, you also want to reset the image to nil, otherwise a reused cell may contain old data. `cell.imageView.image = nil; // Or placeholder image`

Comment: Good call. Knew I was forgetting something. This should go in the cell’s `-prepareForReuse` or at the top of the method in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small 'tutorial' in answer to a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14623686/1375695). Although the question refers to Core Data, my answer applies to any data source so you should be able to fit it around your use case.

One thing you want to watch out for is the inner block, when you get back onto the main queue. Given that you have no idea how long it takes to get to that point, the cell may no longer be relevant to that image (could have been reused), so you need to do a couple of additional checks...

(a) is the image still required?

```
if ([[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath])
```

(b) is *that* cell is the correct cell for the image?

```
 UITableViewCell * correctCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Although this tutorial is still valid, I tend to abstract things further these days. As the viewController has to deal with thread-unsafe entities like UIKit and Core Data, it is a good idea to keep *all* viewController code on the main thread. Background queue abstractions should take place at a lower level, preferably in the model code.