# UITableView lag when image load in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm using `coredata`. I successfully added the image in my `coredata` but the problem when I want to display the list. I get this lagging problem when I scroll down the `UITableView`. I read this post [Loading image from CoreData at cellForRowAtIndexPath slows down scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623686/loading-image-from-coredata-at-cellforrowatindexpath-slows-down-scrolling/14624875#14624875). I still get the lag and now I'm trying to use the `LazyLoadImage` but the problem is, they are not using `viewdidload()`. I don't know  this `LazyLoadImage`. I want to learn more about Grand Central Dispatch and how this things work.

Here's my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"imageCell";
    
    NSManagedObject *coreData = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
   
    ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ImageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    
   
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       
       
       UIImage *imagex = [cache objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:indexPath.row]];
       UIImage * rowImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[coreData valueForKey:@"image"]];
       UIImageView * myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:rowImage];
       myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
       myImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 79, 56);
       
        cell.name.text = [coreData valueForKey:@"name"];
        if (imagex == nil) {
            
            [cache setObject:myImage.image forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:indexPath.row]];
            
          
            imagex = [cache objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:indexPath.row]];
        }
       if(imagex){
       
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

               if ([[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
                   //check that the relevant data is still required
                   UITableViewCell * correctCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                   //get the correct cell (it might have changed)
                   [[correctCell imageView] setImage:imagex];
                   [correctCell setNeedsLayout];
               }
           });
       }
   });
   

    return cell;
    
}
```

Does performance matter if i put my list in inside the controller? I'm not using xib here.

[image]

The problem here is just the first load. When it scroll down. Some code is familiar. I'm trying to solve it in my own, but no luck now. I already read the important of GCD in our app.
Please help me to learn more about this.

**UPDATE**
The images came from the camera I captured. I think I need to resize it.

Comment: `self.devices` is your array where you load the tableView?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs yes. that's the one who hold the list of data from coredata.

Comment: how large is your dataset?  Specifically - is it so large that you actually need to retrieve the data only when you need it, or could you hold it in memory?

Comment: One more question, you're using a custom `UIImageView` and not the default `contentView`'s `imageView` property?

Comment: sorry, I don't get the mean of dataset. Where I can see that dataset?

Comment: Yes not the default UIImageView. Does is matter?

Comment: how many entries do you expect in self.devices?

Comment: @Russell I want display 50 entries, but i don't know if this will affect the performance.

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter as long as the names of the properties are different.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you setNeedsLayout after setImage ? I do not think it is necessary.

Comment: I just copy it to other post. I will remove it

Comment: still the same. I get lag in first load

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is 50 entries, you can load them all - in a background queue - and populate self.devices with the images.  You can initiate that population in viewDidLoad, or whenever you need to refresh

Within cellForRowAtIndexPath(), you will need to check that the data has been populated - first time through it might not be for the top of the table - and display a 'waiting' image or message

Within your data load, you should call reloadData() every 10 records or so, and once at the end to make sure that you update the table view when data is available.

With this approach, you don't see the time taken to load any more than the first few entries in the table, and performance looks good to the user

Comment: The problem here is the first load when I scroll down. I will try your advice

Comment: By the way. Image size is very big. Does it matter the image size?

Comment: depends on HOW big!  If you can load all 50 images in one go, then you will get better speed in moving about your tableview.  If 50 images are so big that loading them all crashes the device, then performance will not be so good :-)

Comment: if they are really big, how about loading a preview image in the table, and only loading the full size one when you select it.  There will be a delay while it's loaded, but unless you're planning to action every row in your table, the performance hit will be reduced.

Comment: I think the size of the image is 1905 x1876. That image came from the camera I captured. I will try your advice here

Answer (score 1):

By threading the creation of your image, you are not guaranteed that the image is returned to the cell faster than the `UITableView` scrolls.

Your cells are reused, so I'm not sure you need this code

```
if ([[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
               //check that the relevant data is still required
               UITableViewCell * correctCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This can cause problems because if a cell is partially or was partially on the screen, you'll get a cell back that isn't visible to a user or one that is partially visible.

Your problem is the first load. The OS caches the image when you use `setImage` so that there's no lag after the first load so a lot of your caching code has no effect since the first setting of the image requires initializing the object, then the OS caches it.

Your images are also huge, I'd downscale unless you need fullscreen on the iPad.

Comment: Yes the images is very huge. I'm still studying here to make the image reduce. I will update you. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to store the images in the Mobile directory than in the core data , As core data is not efficient to store images in it.

You can store the images the example code
 1. Store All images in array  called imageArray

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/%@",self.projectName ]];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];


    for (int i=0; i< self.imageArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *savedImagePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"%i.png",i ]];
        UIImage *image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:savedImagePath error:&error];

        }

     [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
     // 


    }
```

3. Then you can store the address of the image in core data and easily retrieve from the the directory using

```
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"imageCell";

    NSManagedObject *coreData = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ImageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
UIImage *imagex = [cache objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:indexPath.row]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/%@",self.projectName ]];

    NSString * imgPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/image%@",indexPath.row]];
      NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgPath]];

       UIImage * rowImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
       UIImageView * myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:rowImage];
       myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
       myImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 79, 56);

        cell.name.text = [coreData valueForKey:@"name"];
        if (imagex == nil) {

            [cache setObject:myImage.image forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:indexPath.row]];


            imagex = [cache objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:indexPath.row]];
        }
```

Comment: thanks for this man. I will study this. another knowledge here. I will update you. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing photos, videos or audio in your database (so, any potencially big file), it is HIGHLY recommended to use references to them and use the file system for managing the content specially if you are planning to have hundreds, maybe thousands of records or more.

Note: Don't forget to load the files asynchronously as well.

> **Something to remember:** When you fetch the data everything takes memory...

..

**Try this workaround:**

- Open your data model
- select the entity that stores the attribute "image"
- select the attribute that stores the image,
- then in the right menu "Data Model Inspector",
- select:

  - "Store in External Record File"

That will do the trick :)